# Accessing row items when using a custom list view android

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm using a Custom list view to create a list view that contains a switch and a text view on each row. Each row is created from an xml file named row.xml and the list view is inside the main activity xml file. These 2 xml files can be seen below.

**HomeActivity.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#0099cc" tools:context=".Activities.HomeActivity">

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="#ff69539d">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/switch"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Switch Name"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/switch"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/switch"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I use a custom list adapter to populate the listview with the text for the textfields. This can be seen below.

**customlistAdapter**

```
 public class customListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context context;
    String[] switchName;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public customListAdapter(Context context, String[] data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
        this.switchName = data;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return switchName.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return switchName[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View vi = convertView;
        if (vi == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        TextView text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Switch mySwitch = (Switch) vi.findViewById(R.id.switch);
        mySwitch.setTag(position);
        text.setText(switchName[position]);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

The list adapter is created from the main activity as you can see below.

**MainActivity**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(new customListAdapter(this, new String[]{"Switch 1", "Switch 2 ", "Switch 3", "Switch 4", "Switch 5", "Switch 6", "Switch 7"}));

    }
}
```

The problem that I am having is being able to access the switches that are created within the custom list adapter from the main activity. I need to be able to maintain a reference to all of the switches from the main activity so that I can change the states. Ideally i'd be able to have a list or array of each of the switches in the mainActivity. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

in your adapter class, add something like:

```
private OnCheckChangedListener mOnCheckChangedListener;
public void setOnCheckChangedListener( OnCheckChangedListener listener ){
  mOnCheckChangedListener = listener;
}
```

then in the adapter's `getView` method, do something like:

```
mySwitch.setOnCheckChangedListener( mOnCheckChangedListener );
```

then in the activity, so what you want:

```
private OnCheckChangedListener mOnCheckChangedListener = new OnCheckChangedListener(){
  @Override
  onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
    // keep a list of what was checked
  }
}
```

and set it on the adapter:

```
BaseAdapter adapter = new customListAdapter(this, new String[]{"Switch 1", "Switch 2 ", "Switch 3", "Switch 4", "Switch 5", "Switch 6", "Switch 7"});
adapter.setOnCheckChangedListener( mOnCheckChangedListener );
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: This will tell me when one of the switches is checked however is it possible to be able to change the state of the switch programmatically from the main activity? So something like myswitch.setChecked(true); I feel that to be able to do that I'd need to somehow have a list of all of the switches that were created stored within the main activity.

Comment: @Kraze you can do whatever you want in that `onCheckChangedListener`, you have access to the switch instance in the `buttonView` argument

Comment: Not had a chance to try this out yet but my understanding is that when using the onCheckChangedListener I will not be able to access the switch until it has been manually switched by the user? correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @Kraze - that's correct.  Those other switches will not even have been created at runtime, and won't be until they're requested by the ListView when the viewport state would expect it.  if you want to have data available to multiple activities, you'll need to either pass them back and forth as Parcelables stored on the Intent that launches the Activity, or store them as a static member, on properties of a single, or on an Application subclass.